AssertionError: expected +0 to be 3; vi.spyOn()
In attempting to record the number of mock calls of Math.floor() within the function set_rgb_color, the following error is raised:
AssertionError: expected +0 to be 3 // Object.is equality

- Expected
+ Received

- 3
+ 0


Within the test, I'm expecting the mocked function to be called 3 times yet it's returning 0.
test.utils.js
import { vi } from "vitest";

import { set_rgb_color } from './utils.js';

test("Verify that set_rgb_color returns a string representing a rgb color", () => {
     const mock_math_floor = vi.spyOn(Math, "floor");
     mock_math_floor.mockReturnValueOnce(210);
     mock_math_floor.mockReturnValueOnce(55);
     mock_math_floor.mockReturnValueOnce(111);
     const rgb_color = set_rgb_color();
     expect(mock_math_floor.mock.calls.length).toBe(3);
     expect(rgb_color).toBe(`rgb(210, 55, 11)`)
});


utils.js
function set_rgb_color() {
    return `rgb(${new Array(3).map(
        () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
    ).join(",")})`;
}

export { set_rgb_color };

